# Active Record :includes with limit and order by foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
Post.includes(:comments).order('timestamp DESC'.limit(5).to_a.size
```

returns 5 and produces this SQL code:

```
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" ORDER BY "posts"."timestamp" LIMIT 5
SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."commentable_type" = 'Post' AND "comments"."commentable_id" IN (517, 516, 515, 514, 513)
```

---

But when I try to add comments sorting:

```
Post.includes(:comments).order('posts.timestamp DESC').order('comments.timestamp ASC').limit(5).to_a.size
```

It returns 1 and produces this SQL code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "posts".id, posts.timestamp AS alias_0, comments.timestamp AS alias_1 FROM "posts" LEFT OUTER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."commentable_id" = "posts"."id" AND "comments"."commentable_type" IN ('Post') ORDER BY posts.timestamp DESC, comments.timestamp ASC LIMIT 5

SELECT "posts"."id" AS t0_r0, "posts"."content" AS t0_r1, "posts"."timestamp" AS t0_r2, "comments"."id" AS t1_r0, "comments"."content" AS t1_r1, "comments"."timestamp" AS t1_r2, "comments"."commentable_id" AS t1_r3, "comments"."commentable_type" AS t1_r4 FROM "posts" LEFT OUTER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."commentable_id" = "posts"."id" AND "comments"."commentable_type" IN ('Post') WHERE "posts"."id" IN (517, 517, 517, 517, 517) ORDER BY posts.timestamp DESC, comments.timestamp ASC
```

---

I think that first query in second case shoul look as first query in first case.
Any idea on how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are referencing another table in your second ActiveRecord query, Rails "smartly" deduces that you want to `eager_load` instead of `preload`.

Reference: http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/